# How to make the myBatis select result(list) be set to object's property?

Tags: mybatis

Generally, myBatis's select method returns single object or generic List types. for example, I want to fetch all students of a class:

```
<select id="fetchStudentsOfClass" parameterType="int" resultMap="resultMapStudent">
    SELECT * FROM students WHERE class_id=#{id}
</select>
```

I can easily get a result like this: `List<Student>`.

Now, if I want to get the result like this rather than `List<Student>`:

```
class MyClass
{
    List<Student> getStudents{return this.students;}
    void setStudents(List<Student> students){this.students = students}
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

how can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what the <collection/> element is for.  It's important that you properly mark both the container and the values with their <id/> so that MyBatis knows how to deal with collapsing multiple rows into one object.

```
<resultMap id="resultMapClass" type="some.package.MyClass" autoMapping="true">
    <id property="classId" column="class_id" javaType="integer"/>
    <collection property="students" ofType="some.package.Student" autoMapping="true">
        <id property="studentId" column="student_id" javaType="integer"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
<select id="fetchStudentsOfClass" parameterType="int" resultMap="resultMapClass">
    SELECT *
    FROM students
    WHERE class_id = #{id}
</select>
```

See http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps for more details.

Comment: Just want to comment that an id classId shown in the resultMap must be added to MyClass, and modify the selection like: SELECT 1 as classId, col1, col2, ...
    FROM students
    WHERE class_id = #{id}    If not, and the fetch gets multiple returns it will cause ...ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: (a number greater than 1)

Comment: @TGU Based on that exception containing a reference to `selectOne` I'm guessing you have a different use case than the original.  Usage of the definition here by definition returns a `List` and should be used with `selectList` (or `selectMany`, etc) collection type selection methods.  This is because multiple students share the same `class_id`.  

I haven't used mybatis in quite some time, but I think if you wish to use a similar datatype as described here -- but only retrieve a single value -- you should look into using `fetchFirst`

Comment: Actually, thinking on this some more, the behaviour you described might be the result of not having the `id` fields correctly defined (or something has changed with how result maps work).  Either way, the modification you mention would result in a `resultMapClass` that has a `classId` that does not match that which was queried for (which in turn may lead unintended changes when writing data back to the db). I would verify you have a `class_id` column (and a `classId` field) in your Student class/data that lines up with the  `class_id`/`classId` of `MyClass`)